# Como extender o CI_Controller para mais de um core?

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller

No Codeigniter pode-se criar na pasta application/core um arquivo `MY_Controller.php` e os controller extendendo desse arquivo, um exemplo basico seria:

```
<?php
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->helper('url');
    }

}
```

O que estou precisando é criar outros arquivos nesse core extendendo o próprio CI_Controller como por exemplo um `MY_Admincontroller.php` e ele iria ter outra modelagem quanto ao MY_Controller, por exemplo:

```
<?php
class MY_Admincontroller extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->helper('admin');
    }

}
```

Só que eu fazendo isso me da um erro de que não encontrou o MY_Admincontroller.

Fatal error: Class 'MY_Admincontroller' not found in ...

Sei que é possível eu criar esse MY_Admincontroller logo abaixo do MY_Controller, no mesmo arquivo e assim da certo, mas com isso o código ficará muito mais poluído. Alguém sabe se é possível fazer o que estou querendo?

Uma forma que da para fazer, bem resumido, mas como eu disse, o código em si fica muito poluído e com isso difícil manutenção

```
<?php
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {}

class MY_Admincontroller extends MY_Controller {}

class MY_Othercontroller extends MY_Admincontroller {}
```

Comment: cola o erro que está dando...

Comment: No seu projeto(raiz) vc tem outros dois subprojetos que utilizam/chamam o mesmo framework porém o o segundo da erro? é essa situação? se for veja se alguma dessas [resposta](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2188364/1342547) ajudam

Comment: @rray entao, nao eh isso nao, na verdade, em um mesmo projeto quero poder criar um MY_Controller que extende de CI_Controller, tambem poder criar MY_Admincontroller que tambem extende de CI_Controller e dai com isso na minha pasta controllers eu posso ter varios controllers, alguns extendendo do MY_Controller e outros de MY_Admincontroller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso simplemente incluindo o arquivo do controller base da seguinte forma abaixo, quando for usá-lo:

```
include_once(APPPATH.'core/Nome_Controller.php');
```

Por exemplo:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

include_once(APPPATH.'core/Admin_Controller.php');

class MySite extends Admin_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('my_site');
    }

}
```

Outra forma, até mais usual, seria utilizando autoload, onde você não precisará fazer include em todos os seus `controllers` do arquivo de controller base. Da seguinte forma:

No final do arquivo `application/config/config.php` ou em qualquer local dele inclua essa função de autoload `load_my_controllers`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
function load_my_controllers($class) {

  $path = APPPATH . 'core/' . $class . '.php';

  if (strpos($class, 'CI_') !== 0 && is_readable($path)) {
    require_once($path);
  }

}

spl_autoload_register('load_my_controllers');
```

Depois de feito isso, agora você pode incluir mais de um controller base na pasta `core` da sua aplicação.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Queria dizer que testei aqui a maneira que o Yure Pereira falou, e funcionou perfeitamente. eu estava tentando resolver esse problema a algum tempo, podem testar, funciona!
OBS.: estou usando a versão 3.1.6 do CI